# Prove a bounded sequence satisfying an inequality converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence such that $x_{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{3}x_{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n}$ for all non-negative integers $n$. How do I prove that the sequence converges?

If I add $\frac{2}{3}x_{n+1}$ to both sides of the original inequality, I can imply that the sequence $y_{n}=x_{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n}$ converges, since it's bounded and monotonically decreasing. letting the limit of that sequence be $L$ then we need to prove that the sequence $x_{n}$ converges at $\frac{3}{5}L$. That's what I'm thinking of but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Now
\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n}=x_{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n}\\
\frac23y_{n-1}=\frac23x_{n}+(\frac{2}{3})^2x_{n-1}\\
(\frac23)^2y_{n-2}=(\frac23)^2x_{n-1}+(\frac{2}{3})^3x_{n-2}\\
\cdots
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-2/3)^ky_{n-k}…$$
You can use this to show that $x_n$ is Cauchy and so converges.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint: you can rearrange the inequality as follows
$$x_{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{3}x_{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n}
\\x_{n+2}\leq  x_{n+1}-\frac{2}{3}x_{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n}
$$so
$$\underbrace{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}_{y_{n+1}} \leq -\frac{2}{3}(\underbrace{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}_{y_n})\\
$$now
$$* \ y_{n+1}\leq -\frac{2}{3}y_{n}\\
** \ y_{n}\leq -\frac{2}{3}y_{n-1}\\
*** \ y_{n-1}\leq -\frac{2}{3}y_{n-2}\\* ,*** \to \ y_{n+1}\leq -(\frac{2}{3})^3y_{n-2}\\ \to 
y_{n+1}\leq -(\frac{2}{3})^3y_{n-2} \leq  -(\frac{2}{3})^6y_{n-5}\leq -(\frac{2}{3})^9y_{n-8}\leq \cdots$$ now take apart for $y_{n+1},y_{n},y_{n-1}$
like $3$ geometric progression

Comment: How do you deduce that $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\leqslant\frac23|x_{n-1}-x_n|$ from the fact that $x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\leqslant\frac23(x_{n-1}-x_n)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSanos: O hh   you are right, I make a mistake .i'll fix it

Comment: The sign of $\{y_n\}$ is the problem of your hint.